# Changing the permission of utmp and wtmp

Tags: permissions, user-management

I would like to change the permission of `/var/log/wtmp` and `/var/run/utmp` to 660 so that users cannot gain more info about the system (in this case, the logged in users). Does this have any negative side effect on other system programs?

PS. I would change the permission of `/var/log/wtmp` through `/etc/logrotate.conf` and the permission of `/var/run/utmp` through `/etc/init.d/bootmisc.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Changing it to 660 does not cause any problems if you do it through logrotate.conf. That is the proper way to do it.

You can however test it by changing it manually

```
sudo su
chmod 660 /var/log/wtmp
```

would be the 2 commands to do this. For example the command "last" will then show a "permission denied".

Setting it to 644 will cause problems though: the file will no longer be updated except for the users in the group (and there should be none in it).

Same goes for "utmp".

Commands related to these 2 files are for instance "last", "w" and "who". And you can always set the permissions back using the 2 commands I posted in the beginning of this answer.